# Passing data througth activities

Tags: android

I would like to pass data from an activity to an other using intent but it won't work.
I think I did something wrong in my code.

```
        if (condition) {
            Hero = arrayP.get(0).name;
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
            i.putExtra("name");
            startActivity(i);

        }
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look for it to work properly you should make the following changes.

you must change this:

```
        if (condition) {
            Hero = arrayP.get(0).name;
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
            i.putExtra("name");
            startActivity(i);

        }
```

to:

```
            if (condition) {
                String heroName = arrayP.get(0).name; // assuming that name is a String and that arrayP is a Hero Array
                Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
                i.putExtra("name", heroName); // change
                startActivity(i);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Fra,

You code is bit incorrect. You can pass data from one activity to another activity by using

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
i.putExtra("Key", "Value");
startActivity(i);
```

And inside Activity3, you can get data using

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("Key");
```

Also as this is very simple part, you should research it on google before asking in Stackoverflow.